# regex for matching numbers and dashes when in valid

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex `[0-9-]{4}-[0-9-]{2}-[0-9-]{2}$`.

I want it not to match when it is an iso date:

e.g. `1970-01-01`

But I would like it to match when it is like `1979------` or `--------29`.

or `-----11---`.

If I was using just javascript I would say `str.indexOf('--') !== -1`

Comment: What about a year and month, but no day?  Would that also be valid?

Comment: can you add some valid tests and invalid tests for clarity

Comment: What about `----------` or `--79------` (partial numbers or two-digit year numbers)?

Comment: Also what about `123-------`? or `12------34`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following pattern satisfactory:

```
^(?=.*\-\-)(?=.*[0-9]{2})(?:[0-9]{4}|\-{4})-(?:[0-9]{2}|\-{2})-(?:[0-9]{2}|\-{2})$
```

The first lookahead at the start of the pattern asserts that `--` appears at least once, ensuring that the date is not a complete ISO date.  The second lookahead asserts that at least one date component is present, preventing `----------` from being a match.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick with a negative lookahead like this:

```
(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})^[0-9-]{4}-[0-9-]{2}-[0-9-]{2}$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uoxCh7/1)**
[image]

Btw, you can shorten your regex like this:

```
(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})^[\d-]{4}-[\d-]{2}-[\d-]{2}$
```

Update: as [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels) mentioned in his comment, you can make the regex more efficient by using anchors in the lookarounds like this:

```
^(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[0-9-]{4}-[0-9-]{2}-[0-9-]{2}$
```

Comment: `^(?!\d+-\d+-\d+$)[0-9-]{4}-[0-9-]{2}-[0-9-]{2}$` is much more efficient.

Comment: @ctwheels nice to know! Thanks will update the answer with that.

Comment: Your pattern would match `2-1--04-30` and other similar inputs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen true, noticed that as well lol. Have just fixed.